# How to validate an object returned from db using nest js class-validator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I need to check if some datas (which can be optional in db(typeorm entity) level) is not empty using class-validator dto for user activation after reading these data from user db .

> Controller level validations for body, query and all using class-validator is working fine for me

DTO file

```
export class UserActiveDTO {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    readonly id: string;
  
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    readonly name: string;
  
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    readonly role: string;

    //.. other data validations
}
```

Service File

```
// after reading user form findOne (typeorm)
let userCanBeActive: boolean = false;
try {
    const canActiveUser: UserActiveDTO = user;

    // tried to validate user using validate form class-validator
    const vErrors = await validate(canActiveUser, {});
    if (vErrors.length > 0) throw vErrors;
    
    userCanBeActive = true;
  } catch (error) {
    userCanBeActive = false;
}
```

My above code always gives userCanBeActive true, even if the user is missing some of the property I mensioned in DTO file.
What is best practice of validating these type of scenarios in nest js ?

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet that `user` is not an instance of `UserActiveDTO` and it just satisfies the interface. [class-validator does not work on plain objects](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-plain-objects) so you must convert the object into a class instance for `validate` to work

Comment: user is an instance of User entity, I mapped it to canActiveUser by specifying the type UserActiveDTO, so canActivateUser should be an instance of  UserActiveDTO. Isn't that how it works.

Comment: You specified a type for _Typescript_. You didn't change the instance though. If you were to log `user` you'd still get the class type of `User`. Or in other words, if you tried `user instanceof UserActiveDTO` you'd get `false`. That would need to be `true` for `validate` to work

Comment: what about `canActiveUser`, it should be the type of  `UserActiveDTO` and am validating with `canActiveUser` not `User`. Or Is there any other method to do that?

Comment: Typescript is structurally typed. All you did with the `:UserActiveDTO` is told Typescript that `canActiveUser` should match the _interface_ of `UserActiveDTO`. To actually make it an _instance_ (what class-validator needs) you need to use the `UserActiveDTO` `constructor` (`new UserActiveDTO()`)